# About Mertens' first theorem

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Mertens first theorem states that $ \sum_{ p \le x } \frac{\log p}{p} = \log x + R $ with $| R | \le 2$ .

Is it correct that the limit $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \sum_{ p \le x } \frac{\log p}{p} - \log x $ exists? And if so, can somebody be so kind to post a link where I can find online a proof of the existence of this limit?

Thank you.

Comment: See $(17)$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensConstant.html) and the links concerning $B_3$ for example at [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A083343).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni looks like an answer to the given question, not a comment. BTW: Hi again...

Comment: Hello Raymond, thank you for the quick answer. From the links that you provided, I am now convinced that the limit indeed exists. I will need more time to read the linked papers at OEIS to see if one of them contains a proof.

Comment: Glad it helped @wiskundeliefhebber! I don't know a simple proof of this (which may involve a goot part of the material needed for PNT). Fine continuation,

Comment: Nice to meet you here @draks! An answer would require more work (at least for me) to find something simple, compare the solutions and why not provide a proof... :-) (but I am too busy !). Cheers,

Comment: As an aside, the theorem follows from the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), which states that $p_n\simeq n\ln n$

Comment: One can prove by elementary means that this result is equivalent to the prime number theorem.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the Prime Number Theorem in this form $$\theta\left(x\right)=\sum_{p\leq x}\log\left(p\right)=x+O\left(\frac{x}{\log^{2}\left(x\right)}\right)
 $$ to get by partial summation $$\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{\log\left(p\right)}{p}=\frac{\theta\left(x\right)}{x}+\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\theta\left(t\right)}{t^{2}}dt=\log\left(x\right)+R+o\left(1\right)
 $$ then $$ \limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{\log\left(p\right)}{p}-\log\left(x\right)\right)=\liminf_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{\log\left(p\right)}{p}-\log\left(x\right)\right)=R
 $$ and this prove the existence of the limit.

Comment: Is it possible to modify your proof so that you only use $\theta(x) \sim x$?